# Why is my is my Dobot still moving when pin is LOW

Tags: c++

I linked an arduino mega to my dobot and I am trying to get my Dobot to move when ButtonStateStart == High and stop moving when ButtonStateStart == LOW.However when switch is LOW, the code still runs a few moves() before stopping, instead of stopping at the next move(). I have put down the functions I am using and the Loop.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "Protocol.h"
#include "command.h"
#include "FlexiTimer2.h"
#include "PROTOCOLID.h"
#include "stdint.h"
#include <Arduino.h>



const int CL1 = 3; //Start Suction
const int CL3 = 2; // Stop Suction

const int StartButton = 10;
int ButtonStateStart = 0;

const int StopButton = 4;
int ButtonStateStop = 0;





//Set Serial TX&RX Buffer Size
#define SERIAL_TX_BUFFER_SIZE 64
#define SERIAL_RX_BUFFER_SIZE 256

//#define JOG_STICK 
/*********************************************************************************************************
** Global parameters
*********************************************************************************************************/
EndEffectorParams gEndEffectorParams;

JOGJointParams  gJOGJointParams;
JOGCoordinateParams gJOGCoordinateParams;
JOGCommonParams gJOGCommonParams;
JOGCmd          gJOGCmd;

PTPCoordinateParams gPTPCoordinateParams;
PTPCommonParams gPTPCommonParams;
PTPCmd          gPTPCmd;
PTPJumpParams   gPTPJumpParams;
HOMECmd         ghomeCmd;
WAITCmd         gwaitCmd;


uint64_t gQueuedCmdIndex;

/*********************************************************************************************************
** Function name:       setup
** Descriptions:        Initializes Serial
** Input parameters:    none
** Output parameters:   none
** Returned value:      none
*********************************************************************************************************/
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial1.begin(115200); 
    printf_begin();
    //Set Timer Interrupt
    FlexiTimer2::set(100,Serialread); 
    FlexiTimer2::start();
    pinMode(CL1,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(CL3,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(StartButton,INPUT);
    pinMode(StopButton,INPUT);

    
}

/*********************************************************************************************************
** Function name:       Serialread
** Descriptions:        import data to rxbuffer
** Input parametersnone:
** Output parameters:   
** Returned value:      
*********************************************************************************************************/
void Serialread()
{
  while(Serial1.available()) {
        uint8_t data = Serial1.read();
        if (RingBufferIsFull(&gSerialProtocolHandler.rxRawByteQueue) == false) {
            RingBufferEnqueue(&gSerialProtocolHandler.rxRawByteQueue, &data);
        }
  }
}
/*********************************************************************************************************
** Function name:       Serial_putc
** Descriptions:        Remap Serial to Printf
** Input parametersnone:
** Output parameters:   
** Returned value:      
*********************************************************************************************************/
int Serial_putc( char c, struct __file * )
{
    Serial.write( c );
    return c;
}

/*********************************************************************************************************
** Function name:       printf_begin
** Descriptions:        Initializes Printf
** Input parameters:    
** Output parameters:
** Returned value:      
*********************************************************************************************************/
void printf_begin(void)
{
    fdevopen( &Serial_putc, 0 );
}

/*********************************************************************************************************
** Function name:       InitRAM
** Descriptions:        Initializes a global variable
** Input parameters:    none
** Output parameters:   none
** Returned value:      none
*********************************************************************************************************/
void InitRAM(void)
{

    

    //Set PTP Model
    gPTPCoordinateParams.xyzVelocity = 200;
    gPTPCoordinateParams.rVelocity = 200;
    gPTPCoordinateParams.xyzAcceleration = 200;
    gPTPCoordinateParams.rAcceleration = 200;
    SetPTPCoordinateParams(&gPTPCoordinateParams, true,  &gQueuedCmdIndex);
    ProtocolProcess();

    gPTPCommonParams.velocityRatio = 200;
    gPTPCommonParams.accelerationRatio = 200;
    SetPTPCommonParams(&gPTPCommonParams, true, &gQueuedCmdIndex);
    ProtocolProcess();

    gPTPCmd.ptpMode = MOVL_XYZ;
   
   
    

    gQueuedCmdIndex = 0;
    
}
void Suck()
{
  digitalWrite(CL1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(CL3,HIGH);
}
void StopSuck()
{
  digitalWrite(CL1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(CL3,LOW);
  
}

void PutDown()
{
                gPTPCmd.z = 40;
                
                SetPTPCmd(&gPTPCmd, true, &gQueuedCmdIndex);
                ProtocolProcess();
                
                gPTPCmd.x = 0;
                gPTPCmd.y = 250;
                gPTPCmd.z = 10;
                gPTPCmd.r = 0;

                SetPTPCmd(&gPTPCmd, true, &gQueuedCmdIndex);
                ProtocolProcess();

                gPTPCmd.z = -10;
                
                SetPTPCmd(&gPTPCmd, true, &gQueuedCmdIndex);
                ProtocolProcess();

                delay(1000);

                StopSuck();

                gPTPCmd.z = 40;
                
                SetPTPCmd(&gPTPCmd, true,  &gQueuedCmdIndex);
                ProtocolProcess();

               
}

void move1()
{               
                gPTPCmd.x = 235;
                gPTPCmd.y = 0;
                gPTPCmd.z = 40;
                gPTPCmd.r = 0; 

                SetPTPCmd(&gPTPCmd, true, &gQueuedCmdIndex);
                ProtocolProcess();

                gPTPCmd.z = -30;
             
                SetPTPCmd(&gPTPCmd, true, &gQueuedCmdIndex);
                ProtocolProcess();

                Suck();
                delay(1300);
}

void move2()
{            
                gPTPCmd.x = 255;
                gPTPCmd.y = 0;
                gPTPCmd.z = 40;
                gPTPCmd.r = 0; 

                SetPTPCmd(&gPTPCmd, true, &gQueuedCmdIndex);
                ProtocolProcess();

                gPTPCmd.z = -30;
                
                SetPTPCmd(&gPTPCmd, true, &gQueuedCmdIndex);
                ProtocolProcess();

                Suck();
                delay(1300);
}

void move3()
{             
                gPTPCmd.x = 275;
                gPTPCmd.y = 0;
                gPTPCmd.z = 40;
                gPTPCmd.r = 0; 

                
                SetPTPCmd(&gPTPCmd, true, &gQueuedCmdIndex);
                ProtocolProcess();

                gPTPCmd.z = -30;
                
                SetPTPCmd(&gPTPCmd, true, &gQueuedCmdIndex);
                ProtocolProcess();  

                Suck();
                delay(1300);

}

void move4()
{

                gPTPCmd.x = 295;
                gPTPCmd.y = 0;
                gPTPCmd.z = 40;
                gPTPCmd.r = 0; 

          
                SetPTPCmd(&gPTPCmd, true, &gQueuedCmdIndex);
                ProtocolProcess();

                gPTPCmd.z = -30;
               
                SetPTPCmd(&gPTPCmd, true, &gQueuedCmdIndex);
                ProtocolProcess(); 

                
               gPTPCmd.z = 40;
               SetPTPCmd(&gPTPCmd, true, &gQueuedCmdIndex);
               ProtocolProcess();

               Suck();
               delay(1300);
}

    void loop() 
{

    ButtonStateStart = digitalRead(StartButton);
    
    InitRAM();
  
    ProtocolInit();
    
    printf("\r\n======Enter demo application======\r\n");
    
    for(; ;)
    {
        static uint32_t timer = millis();
        static uint32_t count = 0;
        #ifdef JOG_STICK
        #else
        if(millis() - timer > 2000)
        {
            timer = millis();
            count++;
            ButtonStateStart = digitalRead(StartButton);
            while (ButtonStateStart == HIGH)
            {
      
                  move1();
  
                  ButtonStateStart = digitalRead(StartButton);
                  PutDown();
                  if (ButtonStateStart == LOW)
                  { break;
                  }
  
                  move2();
                  
                  ButtonStateStart = digitalRead(StartButton);
                  PutDown();
                  if (ButtonStateStart == LOW)
                  { break;
                  }
  
  
                  move3();
  
                  ButtonStateStart = digitalRead(StartButton);
                  PutDown();
                  if (ButtonStateStart == LOW)
                  { break;
                  }
  
  
                  move4();
  
                  ButtonStateStart = digitalRead(StartButton);
                  PutDown();
                  if (ButtonStateStart == LOW)
                  { break;
                  }
  
                
                  
              }
          }
          #endif
      }
```

Comment: How did you determine that "a few more moves" happened? It could be all kinds of reasons, depending on that. For example, there could input latency or rotational inertia, or if this is a stepper motor, your partial moves might result in a state that is not holding correctly. As a side-note, consider condensing all this duplicated code into one loop. You only need to test the button state and then execute one of the functions. You could have a counter that cycles from 0 to 3, and indexes an array of function pointers to run the correct `move` instruction.

Comment: Seeing `InitRAM();

ProtocolInit();` and an endless loop inside the loop irritates me. If you leave the loop within the loop with a `break`, the outer loop will soon be restarted.

Comment: @paddy I do not understand what you mean by "counter that cycles from 0 to 3, and indexes an array of function pointers to run the correct move instruction" and condensing duplicated code into a loop. Which codes should I condense and in what way would be effective? Sorry for the amateurish questions I am still very new to coding C++ and Arduino.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. I want to see your other function.

Comment: @LookAce Here is a simulation of what I'm recommending: https://godbolt.org/z/7xWTjMeEK it might not necessarily fix your problem, because as I mentioned in my first comment it's a bit unclear what exact behavior you're seeing. But I think you can agree that there is less code duplication, which means there's less places for bugs to appear.

Comment: I'm actually considering that you might have a situation where you pressed and released the button, and then you pressed it again. If these moves are actually important to be executed sequentially (as I suspect for stepper motors), then my solution _might_ actually fix this because they pick up again from wherever they left off whereas yours always start from move1.

Comment: @paddy It is supposed to be a switch not a button, sorry for not being clear, when the switch is on == HIGH the loop continues, until I turn it off == LOW, it should stop at the next PutDown() function, however when I turn it off it == LOW, the Dobot continues the usual actions for about 2 or 3 more move() and PutDown() functions. Before it eventually stops. I have looked at your code however I do not want it to move a static amount of times, I want it to move until I turn the Dobot switch ==LOW.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand,. I do not have the switch or the code that you're calling, nor an Arduino to run it on. I made a _simulated_ function with an arbitrary number of calls before going low. This is meant as a placeholder for the real-world scenario. The function is _not_ the thing you should be deliberating on. I'm showing you the _approach_.

Comment: All this said, go back to my first comment. You still have not proven that the _code_ is the thing that's causing this. There is not enough information to justify your claims. You should at least print out statements showing the value of `ButtonStateStart` after every single call. You might find it goes low, then goes high again. Or you might find there's a delay. You have not shown the move functions or the PutDown function. They could have side-effects. The way to troubleshoot a problem is to take all guesswork and assumptions out of it by rigorously eliminating possibilities.

Comment: @paddy Sorry for misinterpreting your words and code,I have edited the post to show all the functions I am using, I will further work on the possibility elimination.Thank you for explaining your thought process and the approach. Greatly appreciated. Apologies for the misunderstandings.

Comment: @paddy I have checked with the Serial Monitor that ButtonStateStart is High, however the packets are being sent at a extremely fast rate, I believe that the machine is unable to execute as fast as the packets are being sent. But I am unsure. Could that be the case?And that is why the machine moves a few more times before stpping?

Comment: Sounds reasonable. I can't answer. Never written anything serious for Arduino. I thought you were reading a GPIO pin or something. If you're processing data from serial then it's possible. Try emptying the queue before you proceed. Like keep updating button state until there's no more messages. I can't help you any further without physically having your entire hardware and software setup on my desk. Good luck.